# asp.net Web API retrieve file(s) without saving them

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to retrieve file(s) with ASP.NET Web Api, XML file(s) or zip file(s).
There are many examples how to do this, like this:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

But the problem is, I don't want to save them on HDD!
I just want to validate the XML with some functions and generate a report on the fly and want to return this report.
But every tutorial use the "MultipartFormDataStreamProvider" witch save the files on HDD.

How can I get the file(s) and file name(s) in memory?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the MultipartMemoryStreamProvider?

See [a way to implement file upload without writing to the file system.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1842441.aspx/1)

Comment: Hmm...I'm missing something, how can I check which type of file (XML or zip) it is?